# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level in python 3, idk the reason why

Tags: python, indentation

```
number = 64
running = True

while running:
        guess = int(input("write the number :"))
    if guess == number:
            print("Congrads! You won!")
            running = False
    elif guess < number:
        print("No, the number is a bit bigger")
    else:
        print("No, the number is less")
else:
    print("while cycle is over.")
else:
    print("end")
```

i expected a working code, but there's bugs i can't see, it says the problem in line four, but again, i can't see nothing wrong with it

Comment: `guess =` is indented further than it should be, as is the block under your first `if guess ==`. In python, indentation is very specific

Comment: the problem is in line 6

Comment: `else:` without an `if` or `for`/`while` is an invalid syntax.

Comment: The problem is on line 5, 7, 8, (possibly 13, 14), 15, 16

Comment: See the official PEP 8 guidelines on indenting code blocks: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to G. Anderson you have following errors in the code (look comments):

```
number = 64
running = True

while running:
        guess = int(input("write the number :")) # <-- is indented too much
    if guess == number:
            print("Congrads! You won!") # <-- also indented "two tabs"
            running = False # <-- also indented "two tabs"
    elif guess < number:
        print("No, the number is a bit bigger")
    else:
        print("No, the number is less")
else:
    print("while cycle is over.")
else: # <-- second else?
    print("end")
```

This would be a fix:

```
number = 64
running = True

while running:
    guess = int(input("write the number :"))
    if guess == number:
        print("Congrads! You won!")
        running = False
    elif guess < number:
        print("No, the number is a bit bigger")
    else:
        print("No, the number is less")
else:
    print("while cycle is over.")
```